get text inside <span> urn: </span> web scraping
i am trying to get the urn value. starting with the 333
from these lines (link i cant provide for security reason)
<body>
    <div class="receipt-container">
        
<div class="header">
    <div class="three-column">
        <div class="single-colum">
            <div class="logo-holder">
                <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="tans-info">
                <div class="barcode-holder">
                    <span id="CoverPage2_lblBarCode" class="Barcode" style="font-family: 'Free 3 of 9';">*MB270111404AE*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trans-details">
                    <span class="tans-number">27011140</span>
                    <span class="trans-amount"><strong> رقم الإيصال:</strong> 333297706544052311<br/> <strong> &nbsp;URN :</strong> 333297706544052311<strong> &nbsp; القيمة:</strong> 1284</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="single-colum">
                <div class="trans-entry">
                    <span class="entry-title">
                        Establishment Name / اسم المنشأة
                    </span>
                    <span class="entry-detail">
                        <div class="long-text">
                            DAYLIGHT
                        </div>
                        <div class="long-text dir-right">
                            &#x645;&#x637;&#x639;&#x645; &#x62F;&#x64A;&#x644;&#x627;&#x64A;&#x62A; &#x634;.&#x630;.&#x645;.&#x645;
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <div class="trans-entry">
                <span class="entry-title">
                    Type of Transaction / نوع المعاملة
                </span>
                <span class="entry-detail">
                    <div class="long-text">
                        Submit Renew 
                    </div>
                    <div class="long-text dir-right">
                        Labour Card Application
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

i have done this lines of code in python using beautifulsoup4
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r = requests.get(url)    

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") 

desc = soup.find('div', class\_="single-colum").find_all('span')  

for uname in desc:     

urnum = uname.find_all('strong')  

s = urnum  print(s\[1\])   

output:
<strong>  URN :</strong>
what i want to get is this
output:
333297706544052311
also i want to get  the text
Submit Renew
Labour Card Application

Format your code properly (including indentation).

You can use find by text method along with Type of Transaction. In order to get the desired results.
transaction_type = soup.find('span', text='Type of Transaction / نوع المعاملة').find_next('div', class_='long-text').text.strip()
transaction_detail = soup.find('span', text='Type of Transaction / نوع المعاملة').find_next('div', class_='long-text dir-right').text.strip()

Find By Text is the key to scrap such items. Please share more details error log if problem presists.
